# Why do I get an SQL error when there is an apostrophe at the end of my URL?

Tags: php, sql-injection

Why do I get an error when I add `'` to the end of a URL? For example : `http://mywebsite.com/singel?id=24'`

I get the following error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\' LIMIT 1' at line 1`

This is shown everywhere if I put `'` after any id in the query string.

What is wrong, and how it can be fixed?
Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to add an apostrophe there?

Comment: cus i have read somewhere in net, that if you get an error,this mean that you are vulnerable to slq injections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are inserting a non-escaped variable in an SQL query. And if this variable happens to contain SQL special chars, this can cause SQL syntax errors or worse.

You need to escape your variables before inserting them in your SQL queries.

Example:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = " . mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

Instead of (**this is WRONG, don't do this**):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $id LIMIT 1";
```

If `$id` is `24'`, the query becomes:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 24' LIMIT 1";
```

As you can see, there is a `'` after `24`, which is a syntax error.

Comment: hello, thank you for the great answer, this is how i have my code 
$id = mysql_real_escape_string ($id);
$sql = 'SELECT id,post_title,post_date,post_content FROM wp_posts WHERE id=62 ORDER BY post_date LIMIT 1';
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());

Answer (score 2):

if a `'` kills your query, you very obviously have an sql injection vulnerability. Read up on [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string), [bobby-tables](http://bobby-tables.com), and consider switching to [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) prepared statements.

Comment: +1 for the BobbyTables-link: "Don't try to escape invalid characters. Don't try to do it yourself. Learn how to use parameterized statements. Always, every single time."

Answer (score 0):

Look here

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SqlInjectionAttacks.aspx

You should learn something about SQL injection. Your Script is injectable now

Answer (score -1):

This error usually means you are open to sql injections. This function is a bit more complicated than mysql_real_escape_string(), because it also does a PHP configuration test, to make sure you do not escape the data twice and to add Various PHP version support! (as per PHP Manual [1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php))
Just run this little nifty function on each of the submitted items, for inserts, updates or where statements:

```
function sql_injection($value){
    $value = trim($value);
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
        $value = stripslashes($value);
    if(function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string")){
        $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    }else
        $value = addslashes($value);
    return $value;
}
```

Ex:

```
$q = 'SELECT `blah` FROM `users` WHERE `id`='.sql_injection($_POST['id']);
```

- This function does NOT replace server side validation, and everything should be validated before using it, always assume the worst :)

Comment: so if i will add `blah` the slasesh it will not show me this error ?

Comment: in the example above blah represents a database field, the example is centered on the sql_injection function, if you use it on the items(variables) that are submitted to the database you should not see this error.

Comment: also this function or simple mysql_real_escape_string(), protects you only from injection, it does not mean that your query will not break. For example for numeric characters, you will get a similar error for 24' or 24\' (the output of mysql_real_escape_string()), that is where server validation comes into place! hope this helps